# ¿Porque "action" en un formulario HTML me envía a un php que no existe?

Tags: php, html, xampp, localhost

Quiero cambiar el parámetro de `action="modificar.php"` a `action="actualizar.php"`
Pero cuando ejecuto mi pagina en localhost y mando datos me sigue enviando a "modifica.php" utilizo XAMPP y la versión del PHP es 7.3.6

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Curso de Bootstrap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/starter-template.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Practica Final</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="inicio.html" tabindex="-1">Inicio</a>
            </li>            
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="agregarAlumnos.html" tabindex="-1">Agregar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="consultaAlumnos.html">Consultar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="eliminarAlumnos.html" tabindex="-1">Eliminar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="modificarAlumnos.html" tabindex="-1">Modificar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">
<h1>Modificar la información del alumno</h1>
    <p class="lead">Este curso es una introduccion a HTML5 y BootStrap.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="actualizar.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtId">ID del alumno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtId" id="txtId" placeholder="ID del alumno" required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtNombre">Nombre del Alumno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNombre" id="txtNombre" placeholder="Nombre del alumno" required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtApellidoP">Apellido Paterno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtApellidoP" id="txtApellidoP" placeholder="Apellido Paterno del Alumno" required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtApellidoM">Apellido Materno</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtApellidoM" id="txtApellidoM" placeholder="Apellido Materno del Alumno" required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nmbCalificacion">Calificación del Alumno</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="nmbCalificacion" id="nmbCalificacion" placeholder="Calificación del Alumno" required="true" min="0" max="10" placeholder="Calificación del Alumno">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar" style="btn-primary">
        
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</main><!-- /.container -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tienes alguno de esos archivos? En caso de no tenerlos, jamas se va a ejecutar dicha `accion`.

Comment: Para eliminar lo obvio: salvaste los cambios y recargaste la página con el formulario modificado?

Answer (score 0):

Algunas veces los problemas que surgen para este tipo de casos tienen su origen en el caché. Por lo general estos datos persisten en el navegador para evitar la carga de datos constantemente y de esta forma ser más eficientes. Como consejo puedes borrar el caché de tu navegador, o también irte a la consola del mismo( este ejemplo para el caso de Chrome), a la pestaña Network y habilitas la opción "Disable cache".

A veces resulta muy útil cuando recargas múltiples veces y no cambia el contenido de la página.

Comment: Como otro aporte para lo de la cache puedes abrir tu pagina en modo incógnito